# VBA - Return ducplicate-txt only if cell headers in row x are equal, else return date from row y corresponding to input-value

Tags: vba, excel

Need help for two things.

Picture of the Excel sheet:

[image]

Number 1:

Another code will paste the highest value of 'Amount due' and 'Due not paid' from row 7 into B1 and B2. From this, I need two codesm one each for 'Amount due' and 'Due not paid', that checks if there are any duplicates of the value from B1 and B2 in row 6. IF there are, then the text 'Several dates with same amount' should be displayed in F1 and F2. IF there aren't then the corresponding date from row 4 should be displayed in F1 and F2.

But there are some exceptions related to the values in row 5. The two codes should work identically, but use 'Amount due' or 'Due not paid' as a basis. To simplify the scenario, Im using the code for 'Amount due' as an example:

- If the input value (B1) appear more than once in row 7 **and** at least two of the appeared values are located under the same value ("Amount due") in row 5, then the output (F1) should be 'Several dates with same amount'
- If the input value (B1) appear more than once in row 7 **and** none of the appeared values are located under the same value ("Amound due") in row 5, then the output (F1) should be the corresponding date value from row 4.

Example related to the picture i linked:

- The highest 'Amount due'-value is 10 (in row 7), and since this value is located in A7 and C7, which both are an 'Amount due' column, then the output in F1 should be 'Several dates with the sam amount'.
- The highest 'Due not paid'-value is 5 (in row 7), and since the value is located in E7 and F7, which are an 'Amound due' and 'Due not paid' column, then the output in F2 should be the corresponding date from row 4 - which in this case is 30.12.16 (which also leads me to my next issue...)

Number 2:

As you can see, each pair of the 'Amount due' and 'Due not paid' columns are linked to one date (i.e. the 'Due not paid' column always belong to the date to its left). Is it possible, in the second scenario described above, that the 'Due not paid' code fetches the date which is located to its left, above the 'Amount due' column. So in the picture, the output in F2 should be 30.12.16 because the code findes the highest value among 'Due not paid' in row 7, which is in column F - and since the duplicate in coulmn E is 'Amount due' the output should be a date.

My current code:

```
Sub test()  

  Dim Range1  As Range  
  Set Range1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A6:F6")  

   For Each cell In Range1  
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range1, Range("B1").Value) > 1 Then  
    ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Value = "Several dates with the same amount"  
   Else  
    ActiveSheet.Range("F1").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(A3:F3,MATCH(B1,A6:F6,0))"  
   End If  
   Next  

End Sub
```

Hope this was understandable.
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your question is overly simplified, relative to what you want, but the following two formulas will return what you show in your picture.  Assuming you have more rows of data, you will need to adapt them to your real situation:

```
F1:  =IF(COUNTIFS($A$5:$F$5,"Amount Due",$A$7:$F$7,B1)>1,"Several dates with the same amount",SUMPRODUCT((A7:F7=B1)*(A5:F5="Amount Due")*A4:F4))
F2:  =IF(COUNTIFS($A$5:$F$5,"Due not paid",$A$7:$F$7,B2)>1,"Several dates with the same amount",SUMPRODUCT((B7:F7=B2)*(B5:F5="Due not paid")*A4:E4))
```

Note that with regard to the formula in F2, to take care of the Offset of the applicable date, we "shorten" the horizontal array by one, and offset it one to the right with regard to the date.

Comment: Hi Ron! Thank you for answering. I have tested a bit and as far as I can see this is working like a champ! I will do some further testing on a real test case scenario today and tomorrow and let you know of the result. But this is looking good (I may have over complicated it when trying to solve it myself). Thank you - much appreciated!